# handle RunTimeException in custom Thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading

[image: After throwing a RunTimeException in a custom thread the thread stopped (like a dead lock) and nothing was loged]

[image: But when I throw the RunTimeException in the renderer thread everything works fine]

I discovered this after I spend a whole day trying to find out why did the thread stopped. The cause turned out to be a simple `IndexOutOfBondException`. If the exception was showed in logcat I would've fixed that in a minute. Can anyone please tell me why throwing a exception in a custom thread causes a thread to stop and how can I catch it and log it?

I used `ExecutorService` to create and handle my custom thread.

```
private ExecutorService processingThread = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor(r -> new Thread(r, "processingThread"));
```

I use android studio.

Code in the second screenshot is inside the function `onDrawFrame()` in `GLRenderer`.

Code in the first screenshot is inside the lambda thingy in the submit function which is in the function `onDrawFrame()` in `GLRenderer`(forgive my english).

thanks a lot

Comment: can you update your question with code rather than screenshot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot catch exception from Thread directly in your main thread.

**When a thread is about to terminate due to an uncaught exception**

> 1. The Java Virtual Machine will query the thread for its UncaughtExceptionHandler using Thread.getUncaughtExceptionHandler()
>      and will invoke the handler's uncaughtException method, passing the
>      thread and the exception as arguments.
> 2. If a thread has not had its UncaughtExceptionHandler explicitly set,
>      then its ThreadGroup object acts as its UncaughtExceptionHandler.
> 3. If the ThreadGroup object has no special requirements for dealing with
>      the exception, it can forward the invocation to the default uncaught
>      exception handler.

You can catch the runtime exception from thread as follows:

```
Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler h = new Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler() {
    public void uncaughtException(Thread th, Throwable ex) {
       Log.e("TEST","Uncaught exception: " + ex);
    }
};
final Thread thread = new Thread() {
    public void run() {
        Log.d("TEST","Performing action...");
        throw new RuntimeException("Exception from thread");
    }
};
thread.setUncaughtExceptionHandler(h);
thread.start();
```

Comment: @ShuangLi no problem. Enjoy coding:-) Remember to upvote & mark answer as approved so that others can benefit too!